# Octave display low brightness images

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, octave, imshow

I using `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')` for Octave.

Here is the original image:
[image]

However, when I use `imshow`, the image seems to be darker:

`image = imread('Lenna.png')
imshow(image)`

[image: imshow Image here]

The gray version is working well:

`pkg load image
gray = rgb2gray(image)
imshow(gray)`

[image: gray image]

What can I do to fix the `imshow` problem?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error.  Using the `gnuplot` graphics package, downloading the original image, reading it in Octave and showing it displays the same image without any decrease in illumination.  I'm also using Octave 4.0.0.

Comment: I am using Arch Linux and all the packages were installed from `pacman`. I am using Octave 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by changing graphics toolkit to `qt`:

```
graphics_toolkit('qt')
```

And you should use `octave` or `octave --no-gui` instead of `octave-cli` because `octave-cli` doesn't link to `qt`.